# How mock a third-party module in Jest/NestJS?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've the following code and I need to mock the `connection.execute()` function as this belongs to the third-party lib `snowflake-sdk` and is't not part of my unit test:

```
import * as SnowflakeSDK from 'snowflake-sdk';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class SnowflakeClient {
  export(bucket: string, filename: string, query: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const connection = this.getConnection();
      const command = `COPY INTO '${bucket}${filename}' FROM (${query})`;
      connection.execute({
        sqlText: command,
        complete: function (err) {
          try {
            if (err) {
              return reject(err);
            } else {
              return resolve(true);
            }
          } finally {
            connection.destroy(function (err) {
              if (err) {
                console.error('Unable to disconnect: ' + err.message);
              }
            });
          }
        },
      });
    });
  }

  getConnection() {
    const connection = SnowflakeSDK.createConnection({
      account: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_HOST!,
      username: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME!,
      password: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD!,
      role: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_ROLE!,
      warehouse: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE!,
      database: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE!,
      schema: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA!,
    });

    connection.connect(function (err: Error): void {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    });

    return connection;
  }
}
```

So I've created the following unit test:

```
import { SnowflakeClient } from 'src/snowflake/snowflake-client';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

describe('SnowflakeClient', () => {
  let snowflakeClient: SnowflakeClient;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [SnowflakeClient],
    }).compile();

    snowflakeClient = moduleRef.get<SnowflakeClient>(SnowflakeClient);
  });

  describe('export', () => {
    it('should export a SQL query', async () => {
      const connectionMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        execute: function (bucket: string, filename: string, sql: string) {
          console.log(`${bucket}${filename}: ${sql}`);
        },
      }));

      jest.spyOn(snowflakeClient, 'getConnection').mockImplementation(connectionMock);
      const bucket = 's3://bucketName';
      const filename = '/reports/test.csv';
      const sql = 'select * from customers limit 100';
      await expect(await snowflakeClient.export(bucket, filename, sql)).resolves.not.toThrow();
    }, 10000);
  });
});
```

But the `connectionMock.execute` isn't being called correctly as I'm getting the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/snowflake/snowflake-client.spec.ts (13.518 s)
  SnowflakeClient
    export
      ✕ should export a SQL query (10018 ms)

  ● SnowflakeClient › export › should export a SQL query

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 10000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      14 |
      15 |   describe('export', () => {
    > 16 |     it('should export a SQL query', async () => {
         |     ^
      17 |       const connectionMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      18 |         execute: function (bucket: string, filename: string, sql: string) {
      19 |           console.log(`${bucket}${filename}: ${sql}`);

      at src/snowflake/snowflake-client.spec.ts:16:5
      at src/snowflake/snowflake-client.spec.ts:15:3
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/snowflake/snowflake-client.spec.ts:4:1)
```

I would like to test the `SnowflakeClient.export()` method but I need to mock the `snowflake-sdk` module as it isn't part of my code.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

When using sdk, it's better to pass them through the injection system of NestJs with a custom provider:

```
//////////////////////////////////
// 1. Provide the sdk in the module.
//////////////////////////////////

const SnowflakeConnectionProvider = {
  provide: 'SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION',
  useFactory: () => {
    const connection = SnowflakeSDK.createConnection({
      account: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_HOST!,
      username: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME!,
      password: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD!,
      role: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_ROLE!,
      warehouse: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE!,
      database: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE!,
      schema: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA!,
    });

    connection.connect(function (err: Error): void {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    });

    return connection;
  },
  inject: [],
}

@Module({
  providers: [
    SnowflakeClient,
    SnowflakeConnectionProvider,
  ]
})
export class SnowflakeModule {}


//////////////////////////////////
// 2. Inject the connection into your `SnowflakeClient`
//////////////////////////////////

@Injectable()
export class SnowflakeClient {
  constructor(@Inject('SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION') private readonly connection: SnowflakeConnection) {}

  // ...
}


//////////////////////////////////
// 3. Mock the dependency in tests
//////////////////////////////////

beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {
        provide: 'SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION',
        useValue: { /* Mock */},
      },
      SnowflakeClient,
    ],
  }).compile();

  snowflakeClient = moduleRef.get<SnowflakeClient>(SnowflakeClient);
});
```

You will have a much better control over the tests.

Comment: Thx a lot, this is the best practice indead.

Comment: How can I test Snowflake in a E2E test?

Answer (score 1):

So I got this fixed doing this (but I'm not sure it's the best way):

```
  const connectionMock = jest.createMockFromModule<Connection>('snowflake-sdk');
  connectionMock.execute = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  });
  jest.spyOn(snowflakeClient, 'getConnection').mockImplementation(() => {
    return connectionMock;
  });
  expect(snowflakeClient.export(bucket, filename, sql)).resolves.not.toThrow();
```

Let me know your thoughts :)

Comment: You are describing mocking a method on the object under test. `jest.spyOn(snowflakeClient, 'getConnection').mockImplementation(...)` when `SnowflakeClient` is what is being tested, really not great